# is there a way to make a plotly trendline intercept specific values?

Tags: python, plotly-python, plotly-express

I would like to know if someone knows of an easy way to make an OLS trendline in ploty express pass through the origin. I have been looking for quite some time now so it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can remove the constant from the regression formula, so that it looks like `y = a * x`, which passes through the origin, because `a * 0 = 0`

Comment: you would most likely get more responses if you can add a screenshot of what your expected output is.

Answer (score 3):

With plotly.express.scatter(), there is a trendline_options variable passed in as a dictionary. Set the add_constant key to False; i.e.

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x=x, y=y, trendline="ols", trendline_options={"add_constant": False})
```